# Swift - SKShapeNode from user-drawn image (using CGMutablePath())

Tags: swift, swift3, drawing, cgpath, skshapenode

everyone!

I bet this is a simple fix but I can't wrap my mind around it. In the game I'm making, I want a user to be able to draw something (a squiggle, a circle, etc.) and make an SKNode (SpriteNode, ShapeNode, etc.) from that drawing. I've almost got it working, but when I draw on the screen, it starts the drawing at a random point in the top right of the screen and flips my finger motions vertically (but not horizontally). To truly get an idea of my problem you might have to see it, so here's my GameScene.swift code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
var swiped = false

var ref = CGMutablePath()
var lineDrawing = SKShapeNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    lineDrawing = SKShapeNode(rectOf: self.frame.size)
    lineDrawing.lineWidth = 10
    lineDrawing.position = CGPoint.zero
    self.addChild(lineDrawing)

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = false

    if let touch = touches.first {

        lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)

    }
}



func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

    ref.move(to: fromPoint)
    ref.addLine(to: toPoint)

    lineDrawing.path = ref
    lineDrawing.lineCap = CGLineCap.round
    lineDrawing.lineWidth = 10
    lineDrawing.strokeColor = SKColor.black//maybe .strokeTexture for chalk

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = true
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let currentPoint = touch.location(in: view)
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

        // 7
        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if !swiped {
        // draw a single point
        drawLineFrom(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
    }

}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
}
```

I would really appreciate some help on this issue :) Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was that I was using "view" instead of "self" in touch.location(in:___) a couple times. For some reason, the origin of "view" is at the top left of the screen, whereas the origin of "self" is at the center of the screen. (it might be the other way around, I forget.